# Netbook power button ineffective after lubuntu 15.10 to 16.04LTS update

Tags: lubuntu, 16.04, shutdown, lxde

A few days ago, I upgraded my eMachines (Acer) netbook from Lubuntu 15.10 to 16.04LTS. Everything works fine, except that the power button no longer brings up the shutdown menu. I tried switching the power button functionality in the power options to plain shutdown, and then back to menu, but it still will not respond.

Comment: Have you checked the Power Management settings within Lubuntu? As I recall, there's an option in there to choose what happens when you press the power button; right now it might be set to "Do Nothing". You can get to the power settings by right-clicking the battery icon in the taskbar.

Comment: Yes, I did. As I said, I switched it to just do a shutdown, and then switched it back to showing the shutdown menu. In either case, nothing happens when I press the power button. It worked fine in 15.10.

Comment: Odd. It suddenly started working, even though I changed nothing (other than installing Audacity, which I'm sure is a coincidence).

Comment: And then after some reboots, it doesn't work. Very strange.

Comment: Further update: I'd given up on trying to make this work, and configured the power settings to do a shutdown instead of bringing up the shutdown menu. This consistently works, except very rarely, when instead of doing a shutdown, it brings up the shutdown menu. To summarize:

Power button set to show menu: button usually does nothing, sometimes brings up the menu.

Power button set to shut down: button almost always does a shutdown, but occasionally brings up the menu instead (button never does nothing).

Answer (score 1):

I finally got sufficiently annoyed by this problem that I spent a few hours trying to fix it. A lot of posts here on askubuntu.com were helpful, and hopefully *this* will help someone else.

Here's what I ended up doing to get it to work ...

First, I set the power button action in the power manager preferences to "Do Nothing", as I didn't want this to interfere with anything (recall that the button *sometimes* did something).

Next, I installed ACPI:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install acpi acpid
```

Then I created `/etc/acpi/powerbtn.sh` containing the following:

```sh
# If LXDE is running execute lxsession-logout.

_LXSESSION_PID=`pidof lxsession`

if [ ! -n "$_LXSESSION_PID" ]
then
    /sbin/shutdown -h now "Power button pressed"

elif [ "$2" = "PBTN" ]
then
    export _LXSESSION_PID
    export DISPLAY=:0
    export XUSER=myUserName ## Put your actual user ID here! ##
    export XAUTHORITY=/home/$XUSER/.Xauthority
    logger "Launching lxsession-logout"
    lxsession-logout
fi
```

Next, I created `/etc/acpi/events/powerbtn` containing the following:

```
event=button/power
action=/etc/acpi/powerbtn.sh %e
```

Finally, I restarted the ACPI daemon:

```
/etc/init.d/acpid restart
```

Just a few additional notes:

- This is a single user machine, so I had no qualms about hard-coding my user ID into the script.
- Some posts I read suggested that the `powerbtn.sh` or `events/powerbtn` files would already be there; they weren't.
- The `%e` in the event's action, and the `elif [ "$2" = "PBTN" ]` in the `powerbtn.sh` script, were necessary because pressing the key triggered the event twice, one with a key name of `PBTN`, and once with `LNXPWRBN:00`. Without this, the dialog popped up again if I cancelled the first time.